# Selenium- The method is undefined for the type class. Exception during Java Class extension

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface

I am new to `selenium` and `java` and trying to build a program and facing multiple issues. Listed is the code below for Parent Class.

Login Method error.

> Void is an valid type error on  Syntax error on token "(".

Even though i tried to change, still i face an error

```
package MyfirstMavenProject.Myfirstgmailtest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginClass {

    //Open the Browser
    public  void BrowserOpen (String args[]) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //Get the URL   
    driver.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Identifies the gmail and password
    public void  Login (String args[]) {

    WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.id("Email")); 
    emailfield.sendKeys("abc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();      
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@type='password']"))).sendKeys("abc");   
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();    

    }
    }


}
```

Child Class is where i am getting error on argument. Need info as to what argument should i pass. I am trying to use the Login method created in the above class

```
package MyfirstMavenProject.Myfirstgmailtest;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ComposeEmailClass extends LoginClass {

        //Method to identify the compose email
    public void ComposeEmail (String args[]){

        WebDriver ComposeEmail = new FirefoxDriver();       
        ComposeEmail.findElement(By.className("T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3")).click();
    }` public static void main  (String args[]){

     ComposeEmailClass ClickCompose = new ComposeEmailClass();
     ClickCompose.Login(args);`\\Need more info`
     ClickCompose.ComposeEmail(args);        
 }FireFox.Quit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:
There are lots of syntax error present in your code.

Login Class:  *Corrected*

```
package MyfirstMavenProject.Myfirstgmailtest;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginClass 
{   
    WebDriver driver =null;
    //Open the Browser
    public  void BrowserOpen (String args[]) 
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Get the URL   
        driver.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    //Identifies the gmail and password
    public  void Login (String args[])
    {

        WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.id("Email")); 
        emailfield.sendKeys("youremail@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();      
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*    [@type='password']"))).sendKeys("password");   
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();    
   }
}
```

ComposeEmailClass: *Corrected*

```
package MyfirstMavenProject.Myfirstgmailtest;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 public class ComposeEmailClass extends LoginClass 
 {

    //Method to identify the compose email
     public void ComposeEmail(String args[])
     {
        WebDriver ComposeEmail = new FirefoxDriver();       
        ComposeEmail.findElement(By.className("T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3")).click();
     } 
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         ComposeEmailClass ClickCompose = new ComposeEmailClass();
         ClickCompose.BrowserOpen(args);
         ClickCompose.Login(args);
         ClickCompose.ComposeEmail(args);        
     }

}
```

You have to Call `ClickCompose.BrowserOpen(args);` before `ClickCompose.Login(args);`

and  `String[] args` is not required in your method declaration .